# Why is the last pgfplots tick label not shown in one of my groupplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This drives me crazy. Why is the last tick label shown in one of the groupplots only, despite they are equally defined? It is also not shown if the single plot is plotted.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
ratio,1545ARI,1545IU,2575ARI,2575IU,3595ARI,3595IU
0.5,0.46781,0.55161,0.46235,0.54209,0.45536,0.53538
1.0,0.47004,0.55282,0.46525,0.54487,0.45885,0.53718
1.5,0.47076,0.55349,0.46685,0.54560,0.46029,0.53768
2.0,0.47158,0.55442,0.46913,0.54762,0.46223,0.53996
2.5,0.47227,0.55495,0.47136,0.54886,0.46471,0.54096
3.0,0.47239,0.55517,0.47286,0.55009,0.46665,0.54256
3.5,0.47349,0.55604,0.47388,0.55170,0.46699,0.54300
4.0,0.47342,0.55621,0.47543,0.55287,0.46805,0.54367
4.5,0.47407,0.55643,0.47660,0.55376,0.46836,0.54454
5.0,0.47422,0.55668,0.47563,0.55342,0.47097,0.54620
5.5,0.47431,0.55688,0.47651,0.55385,0.47169,0.54682
6.0,0.47393,0.55679,0.47675,0.55470,0.47298,0.54814
6.5,0.47485,0.55727,0.47660,0.55468,0.47375,0.54848
7.0,0.47476,0.55734,0.47773,0.55550,0.47487,0.54872
7.5,0.47484,0.55737,0.47822,0.55578,0.47604,0.54919
8.0,0.47472,0.55750,0.47790,0.55572,0.47564,0.54941
8.5,0.47512,0.55784,0.47831,0.55654,0.47657,0.54992
9.0,0.47530,0.55762,0.47932,0.55683,0.47606,0.54990
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={rows=1,columns=2,horizontal sep=2cm},
    height=7cm, width=7cm,
    grid,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                      /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                      /pgf/number format/zerofill},
    ]
\nextgroupplot[
        ytick={0.535,0.54,...,0.56},
        ymin=0.535,ymax=0.56,xmin=0,xmax=10]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=2575IU] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=3595IU] {data.csv}; 
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=1545IU] {data.csv};
\nextgroupplot[
        ytick={0.455,0.46,...,0.485},
        ymin=0.455,ymax=0.485,xmin=0,xmax=10]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=1545ARI] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=2575ARI] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=ratio,y=3595ARI] {data.csv};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: I don't know why the tick is not shown (maybe some rounding error). However, I found out that if you delete the `ytick={}` line and add `try min ticks=6,` it seems to work.

Comment: This is indeed a very cool option! Never knew that there is a tick fine tuning section in the manual...

Comment: A demonstration of the problem: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0.455,0.46,...,0.485}
  \x;
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combination of numerical inconsistencies and auto resizing. The foreach syntax uses the TikZ backend and due its implementation it might not hit the last point if the step size is contaminated with numerical noise. Also you are trimming right at the tick location for `ymax` so that needs a nudge too. So for the left one the float representation is better but the right one goes wrong.

Using the slightly nudged options shows the missing tick:

```
    ytick={0.455,0.46,...,0.48505},
    ymin=0.455,ymax=0.48505,
```

Comment: Ok, I expected something like this. The fact that this range definition doesn't crash is interesting. Good to know! In the end I switched to the solution proposed by @LucaD in the comments, as it looks much cleaner. :D