# ifthenelse inside TikZ: not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, ifthenelse

I would like to to get this:

[image]

I tried using `ifthenelse` inside `foreach` but I get an error: `Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.9 }`. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph) esdd says "`\ifthenelse` is "normal" LaTeX code. Therefore you can not use this command inside a TikZ path specification." However, I do not know how to fix this the problem.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,0.2,0.4,...,1.6}{
    \ifthenelse{\y==1.6}{\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,1.6) -- (-0.3,1.6) node [above,midway] {U};}{\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,\y) -- (-0.3,\y);}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two things are clear: the test uses just `=`, but it can only compare integers.

Comment: I tried changing the last element of `foreach` from 1.6 to 1; then I tried using `\ifthenelse{\y=1}` but it does not work.

Comment: you need \equal the `=` test in ifthen (not ==) is n `\ifnum` so only for integers

Comment: A third problem: when TikZ comes to 1.6, it evaluates it as 1.59998

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can surely use `\ifthenelse`, but

1. the test compares only integer
2. it uses a single `=`
3. when TikZ comes to 1.6 it actually sees it as 1.59998

Use integers, then:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,2,4,...,16}{
  \ifthenelse{\y = 16}
    {\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,1.6) -- (-0.3,1.6) node [above,midway] {U}}
    {\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,\y/10) -- (-0.3,\y/10)}
  ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain to me what "when TikZ comes to 1.6 it actually sees it as 1.59998" means?

Comment: @Marco The joys of floating point arithmetic in TeX! ;-)

Comment: @Marco see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275056/why-is-the-last-pgfplots-tick-label-not-shown-in-one-of-my-groupplots for a similar problem

Answer (score 12):

An alternative approach would be the standard `\ifnum` construct combined with `\pgfmathparse`. Note that since 1.6 is a float, you must provide a tolerance. A simple `\pgfmathparse{\y == 1.6 ? int(1) : int(0)}` would not work.

Here is the complete solution:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {0,0.2,0.4,...,1.6}{
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\y - 1.6) < 0.001 ? int(1) : int(0)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 
        \draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,\y) -- (-0.3,\y) node [above,midway] {U};
    \else
        \draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,\y) -- (-0.3,\y);
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to add `int()`. That resulted in a weird `Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`

Answer (score 4):

The mandatory `xintexpr` solution. This time I spare you folks the `\xintFor`,  as `\foreach` is too venerable.

I don't know how to tell `\foreach` to expand its list argument first, hence I have to resort to the device from the `TikZ` manual with a `\mylist` definition first.

The method here is for more complicated situation where fixed point operations must be exact.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\mylist{\xinttheiexpr [1] 0..[+0.2]..1.6\relax}% 
% (The [1] is to tell it to use fixed point notation 
% with one digit after decimal mark, and this expands to 
% 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6 )
% 
\foreach \y in \mylist
{%
  \xintifboolexpr{\y = 1.6}
    {\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,1.6) -- (-0.3,1.6) node [above,midway] {U}}
    {\draw [thin,-latex] (-0.8,\y) -- (-0.3,\y)}
  ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```