# Answer Page Not Working

Tags: foreach, exercises

I'm developing worksheets for students to practice determining equations of lines.

Everything is working except for the last command `\ManySolutions`. In fact, the code compiles without it.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Is there some incompatibility with `$$` vs `\(\)` or is `\foreach` incompatible with some other command I put in there?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyScale}{0.4}

\newcommand{\VertLine}
{%
%
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\xvar}{-9}{9}
%
 State the slope, $y_{int}$, and equation in slope-intercept form.

 \newcommand{\Exercise}
  {%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
   \draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid  (10,10); 
   \draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
   \draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
   \draw[thick, blue] (\xvar,-10)--(\xvar,10);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
%
 \newcommand{\Solution}
  {%
   Slope is undefined.

   \ifnum\xvar=0
   {$y_{int}$ is all real numbers.}
   \else
   {There is no $y_{int}$.}
   \fi

   Equation: $x=\xvar$%
   \vspace{1cm}
 }
}


\newcommand{\ManySolutions}{}

\newcommand{\ManyExercises}[1]
{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
  {%
   \VertLine \Exercise \par \vspace{0.5cm}
   \xdef\ManySolutions{\ManySolutions \Solution \par} 
  }
}


\begin{document}

\ManyExercises{15}

\ManySolutions


%It does compile if I replace the two lines above with:
 % \VertLine
 % \Exercise
 % \Solution

% So I know the graph and solutions can be generated.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your code is too complicated for me to give you an answer, but if you put a `\newcommand` within a `\foreach`, at the second step of loop it gives you an error because the command already exists.

Comment: I think your questions (At least with this title does not help anyone else and I suggest to change the title to be near the problem found)

Comment: I edited my answer and gives the wanted results... You can compare with yours and find the problems on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working results for now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}



\newcommand{\MyScale}{0.4}

\newcommand{\Exercise}{}
\newcommand{\Solution}{}
\newcommand{\VertLine}
{%
%
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\xvar}{-9}{9}
%
 State the slope, $y_{int}$, and equation in slope-intercept form.

 \renewcommand{\Exercise}
  {%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\MyScale]
   \draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid  (10,10); 
   \draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
   \draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
   \draw[thick, blue] (\xvar,-10)--(\xvar,10);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
%
 \renewcommand{\Solution}
  {%
   Slope is undefined.
   \ifnum\xvar=0 $y_{int}$ is all real numbers \else There is no $y_{int}$.\fi

   Equation: $x=\xvar$
   \vskip 1cm

 }
}


\newcommand{\ManySolutions}{}



\newcommand{\ManyExercises}[1]
{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
  {%
   \VertLine \Exercise \par \vspace{0.5cm}
   \xdef\ManySolutions{\ManySolutions \Solution\par} 
  }
}

%\renewcommand{\ManyExercises}[1]
%{%
%  \newcount\X
%  \X=1
%  \loop
%  \advance \X by 1
%   \VertLine \Exercise \par \vspace{5cm}
%   \edef\oldManySolutions{\ManySolutions}
%   \xdef\ManySolutions{\oldManySolutions \Solution\par }
%  \ifnum\X<#1
%  \relax
%  \repeat
%}





\begin{document}

%This does not compile...%%%Compiles now
\ManyExercises{10}


\ManySolutions
%It does compile if I replace the line above with:
%% \VertLine
%% \Exercise
%% \Solution

\end{document}
```

The commented way of `\ManyExercises` gives the same results as the above. This way I found out that the problem which remains is the \vspace{1cm} that I have commented out. Of course there is no spaces in the results.

**Edit Replacing `\vspace{1cm}` with \vskip gives the wanted result**

Comment: What do you think is the difference between `\def\Reals{\origmathbb{R}}` and `\xdef\Reals{\noexpand\origmathbb{R}}` (apart from the latter being global, which is irrelevant at that point)?

Comment: @egreg... I just made a million changes to find a way to make it work. It didn't and left on my code something that I don't use. I remember that I tried to keep it unexpanded inside tikz (where didn't work) and let it expand on the text afterwards. Also tried to give an `\empty` value too in some steps and give the old value back later. This just left there. Thanks for noticing. Editting to remove it.

Comment: First, thank you! Also, when I changed your code from `\vskip 1cm` to my original code of  `\vspace{1cm}`, it did not compile. Anyone know what is wrong with `\vspace{1cm}`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Some thoughts and a solution: read @JohnWickerson's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand ... we didn't use `newcommand*` but used `\newcommand` that means that \par and vertical skips are allowed in our command environment. But this environment used inside a `foreach` and thus afaik there needed additional methods for the dimensions since the fontsize there is null. But trying to remove the `foreach` environments and/or even replace all `defs` by `\long\defs` the problem doesn't solve. After checking...

Comment: ... the errors and the long files I found out that `\vspace` gets somehow "undefined" or loosing the dimensions of `cm` `pt` etc. placing all the `\Vertline` command between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and replacing `\vspace{1cm}` with `\@vspace{1cm}` solves the problem. I hope someone who will see these comments will give as the reason. (Still searching)