# Why is tick at position 1 not drawn?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following colorbar drawn with pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    colorbar style={
        width=8cm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xtick={0,0.1,...,1}
    }]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I expected to have x ticks from 0 to 1 in 0.1 increments, but pgfplots omits the tick at 1:
[image]
As a quickfix one can just write 2 instead of 1, then pgfplots draws the tick at 1, but can anyone explain what I did wrong in the first place?

Comment: @percusse This is similar to the answer you already gave at the mentioned possible duplicate.

Comment: Do you also consider it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `xtick={0,0.1,...,1.1}` (`1.1` is the key). I don't know why but I also often run into this issue.

The problem is maybe the same as here: [Why is the last pgfplots tick label not shown in one of my groupplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275056)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    colorbar style={
        width=8cm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xtick={0,0.1,...,1.1}
    }]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well this is the same quickfix as writing 2, in general everything that avoids the rounding difference.

Comment: @TobiBS I did not read what was after your picture:) (saw it on my smartphone). I just added a possible duplicate link.

Comment: thanks for marking at as a duplicate, I couldn't find it while searching before posting. Unfortunately it only supports my fear that the numerics are the problem here and there is no good solution.

Comment: @TobiBS I am afraid so.